# Java generics, how do you say it when reading code out loud?

Tags: java, generics

Just wondering, how would you read out loud the following items using generic types?

```
    1) class Box<T>  
    2) Box<Integer> integerBox  
    3) class Box<T,U>  
    4) <T,U> void doSomething(T t, U u)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
1) class Box<T>                Box of T
2) Box<Integer> integerBox     Box of Integer
3) class Box<T,U>              Box of T,U
4) <T,U> void doSomething(T t, U u)  Just a method which accepts two type parameters T and U
```

---

References:

- [`Generics Tutorial`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)
- [`Java Generics FAQs - Frequently Asked Questions`](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

Comment: Well it's not my downvote, but the question isn't totally constructive. So I'd expect downvotes that aren't constructive.

Comment: @PaulBellora Just curious why is this not constructive? I don't see the generics tutorial actually telling me how to say the terms out loud. I'm not in touch with any other programmers who could tell me this.

Comment: @Sindikalis It's not exactly your fault; it's a good question in general. What I'm saying is there isn't an official resource anywhere that could provide a definite answer. As a result, people will just give opinions and "this question will likely solicit debate", to quote the FAQ.